# How to denest these radicals?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, nested-radicals

I know about the shortcut in which we unnestle radicals but I want to know why it works. For example: How do we unnestle these radicals and solve the problem?

$${1\over \sqrt{7+4\sqrt{3}}} + {1\over \sqrt{7-4\sqrt{3}}}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usual term is "nested radicals", not "nestled radicals".

Comment: They are reciprocal of each other, as it is seen from rationalising denominator.

Comment: The answer is 4 but how should we go about solving it?

Comment: Denominators are $(2\pm \sqrt 3)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple radicals of the form $\sqrt{X\pm Y}$ can be denested with the following identity

$$\sqrt{X\pm Y}=\sqrt{\frac {X+\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}2}\pm\sqrt{\frac {X-\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}2}$$

Where $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}$ and a simplification occurs only when $X^2-Y^2$ is a perfect square. Therefore, it follows that$$\sqrt{7\pm4\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac {7+\sqrt{49-48}}2}\pm\sqrt{\frac {7-\sqrt{49-48}}2}=2\pm\sqrt3$$Can you complete the rest?

---

> **Proof:** Assume $\sqrt{X\pm Y}$ to be equal to $\sqrt{A}\pm\sqrt{B}$ and square both sides. Expanding the right-hand side and setting the two sides equal to each other gives our identity.

Comment: I have never seen this algorithm before..

Comment: @learn2learngoodthings Your welcome. :)

Comment: Thanks again but. I still can't complete the rest through this way. I managed to get 4 which is the right answer through the shortcut but I can't do it through this way for some reason

Comment: This isn't really an algorithm but an identity.

Comment: @Théophile You can write a computer algorithm with the identity.

Comment: @learn2learngoodthings I’m confused by what you mean “can’t do it through this way.” Are you not allowed to use the formula I provided?

Comment: @Crescendo In that sense, every identity is a trivial algorithm, which doesn't seem clear or useful. For example, is it helpful to call Pythagoras's theorem an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$7\pm4\sqrt3=\pm2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt3+2^2+(\pm\sqrt3)^2=(2\pm\sqrt3)^2$$

Now choose the principal values

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Answer (score 0):

$(a+b\sqrt{c})^2
=a^2+b^2c+2ab\sqrt{c}
$.

Put values to generate as many examples as you want.

Answer (score 0):

$$7-4\sqrt3=(2-\sqrt3)^2$$
and $$7+4\sqrt3=(2+\sqrt3)^2$$

Hence $${1\over \sqrt{7+4\sqrt{3}}} + {1\over \sqrt{7-4\sqrt{3}}}  =\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^2+(2-\sqrt3)^2}{(2+\sqrt3)^2(2-\sqrt3)^2}=\frac{8+6}{(4-3)^2} =\color{red}{14}$$